# Test a method in a ViewChild entry component - Angular Jasmine (Isolated Test)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jasmine

I'm practicing tests and I cant't check a method in a ViewChild component. I try to mock it but never works.

**This is my component code**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-test',
  templateUrl: './modal-test.component.html'
})
export class TestModalComponent implements OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('template', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry;

  public componentRef: any;

  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler() {
      this.close();
  }
  constructor(
      public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
      private utilsService: UtilsService
  ) {}

  public showComp(data: { component: any, inputs: any}) {

    this.componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(componentFactory);

    (this.componentRef.instance).data = data.inputs;

    return this.componentRef.instance;
  }

  close() {
      this.utilsService.eventEmitter.emit('close-modal');
      this.activeModal.close();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.entry = null;
      this.componentRef.destroy();
  }

}
```

**This is my Spec.ts code**

```
  it("Test ViewChild", () => {
    spyOn(component.entry, "createComponent");
    let data = { component: 3, inputs: 2};
    component.showComp(data);
  });
```

**This is the error that I get**

*Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for createComponent()*

**This is my code coverage**

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You can't `spyOn` and instance variable, you can only `spyOn` public methods/functions.

To test a `ViewChild` and mock the `ViewChild`, try following this: https://indepth.dev/posts/1184/angular-unit-testing-viewchild. It is well written.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed the steps on that website but still have the same problem, he uses spyOn like me and that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.